# Form Options Date Picker - 1 Year

Tags: php, date, drop-down-menu

I have a script that lets me pick a date from a dropdown list for a full year into the future, so now I want to do the same for a year into the past but reversing it does not work.

Here are my codes:

`1 Year Ahead`

```
<?php
    $day = date('Y-m-d');
    $last_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . '+ 1 year'));
    while($day < $last_day) {
        echo '<option value="'.$day.'">'.date('jS F Y', strtotime($day)).'</option>';
        $day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . ' + 1 day'));
    }
?>
```

`1 Year Into The Past`

```
<?php
    $day = date('Y-m-d');
    $last_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . '- 1 year'));
    while($day < $last_day) {
        echo '<option value="'.$day.'">'.date('jS F Y', strtotime($day)).'</option>';
        $day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . ' - 1 day'));
    }
?>
```

The Furure date picker works fine but the past picker doesn't show any output.  What is the reason for this and what's teh solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should change is change the comparator in the while loop's condition, i.e. the following

```
while($day < $last_day) {
```

to

```
while($day > $last_day) {
```

**Reason**

Since `$day` is today and `$last_day` is a date 1 year in past, ($day < $last_day) condition will never satisfy. Inside every loop, you are decrementing the $day variable by one day, starting from today. So, all you need to do is, render the option tag till the $day variable is greater than the $last_day variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
    $day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year'));
    $last_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . '+ 1 year'));
    while($day < $last_day) {
        echo '<option value="'.$day.'">'.date('jS F Y', strtotime($day)).'</option>';
        $day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . ' + 1 day'));
    }
```

im sure you can see i reduced the start time by adding `strtotime('-1 year')` to your beginning `$day` variable

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the logic is not valid. Change $day to $today just so you can see why, and $last_day to $the_day. You can see that the logic $today < $the_day doesn't make sense if you are looking for the past but $the_day < $today does:

```
<?php
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $the_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today . '- 1 year'));
    while($the_day < $today) {
        echo '<option value="'.$the_day.'">'.date('jS F Y', strtotime($the_day)).'</option>';
        $the_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($the_day . ' + 1 day'));
    }
?>
```